# MySQL class that handles sanitization

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysql, security

I've written a MySQL class that handles sanitization of different data types. The reason I used this (and not prepared statements) is because this can be more dynamic.

Prepared statmenets only supports four data-types:

1. Integer
2. Double
3. String
4. Blob

This limits functionality and it doesn't allow you for example to add dynamic data such as MySQL Keywords, table or field names.

My class handles sanitization of most data types including identifiers such as table names and field names. The idea of the class is based on SafeMySQL (a class already written). I rewrote it for my own so it looks similar. I want to know if anyone could find anything wrong with the class or if he has any comments he'd like to give.

```
<?php
class MySQL {

/**
 * Options that are used to connect to the database
 * @var array
 */
private $opts = array(
    "HOST" => "localhost",
    "USER" => "user",
    "PASSWORD" => "password",
    "DATABASE NAME" => "db_name",
    "CHARSET" => "UTF8"
);

/**
 * Database link
 * @var resource identifier
 */
private $link;

/**
 * Array of reserved MySQL keywords
 * @var array
 */
private $mysqlKeywords = array("ADD", "ALL", "ALTER, ANALYZE", "AND", "AS, ASC", "ASENSITIVE", "BEFORE, BETWEEN", "BIGINT", "BINARY, BLOB", "BOTH", "BY, CALL", "CASCADE", "CASE, CHANGE", "CHAR", "CHARACTER, CHECK", "COLLATE", "COLUMN, CONDITION", "CONSTRAINT", "CONTINUE, CONVERT", "CREATE", "CROSS, CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_USER", "CURSOR", "DATABASE, DATABASES", "DAY_HOUR", "DAY_MICROSECOND, DAY_MINUTE", "DAY_SECOND", "DEC, DECIMAL", "DECLARE", "DEFAULT, DELAYED", "DELETE", "DESC, DESCRIBE", "DETERMINISTIC", "DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW", "DIV", "DOUBLE, DROP", "DUAL", "EACH, ELSE", "ELSEIF", "ENCLOSED, ESCAPED", "EXISTS", "EXIT, EXPLAIN", "FALSE", "FETCH, FLOAT", "FLOAT4", "FLOAT8, FOR", "FORCE", "FOREIGN, FROM", "FULLTEXT", "GRANT, GROUP", "HAVING", "HIGH_PRIORITY, HOUR_MICROSECOND", "HOUR_MINUTE", "HOUR_SECOND, IF", "IGNORE", "IN, INDEX", "INFILE", "INNER, INOUT", "INSENSITIVE", "INSERT, INT", "INT1", "INT2, INT3", "INT4", "INT8, INTEGER", "INTERVAL", "INTO, IS", "ITERATE", "JOIN, KEY", "KEYS", "KILL, LEADING", "LEAVE", "LEFT, LIKE", "LIMIT", "LINES, LOAD", "LOCALTIME", "LOCALTIMESTAMP, LOCK", "LONG", "LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT", "LOOP", "LOW_PRIORITY, MATCH", "MEDIUMBLOB", "MEDIUMINT, MEDIUMTEXT", "MIDDLEINT", "MINUTE_MICROSECOND, MINUTE_SECOND", "MOD", "MODIFIES, NATURAL", "NOT", "NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG, NULL", "NUMERIC", "ON, OPTIMIZE", "OPTION", "OPTIONALLY, OR", "ORDER", "OUT, OUTER", "OUTFILE", "PRECISION, PRIMARY", "PROCEDURE", "PURGE, READ", "READS", "REAL, REFERENCES", "REGEXP", "RELEASE, RENAME", "REPEAT", "REPLACE, REQUIRE", "RESTRICT", "RETURN, REVOKE", "RIGHT", "RLIKE, SCHEMA", "SCHEMAS", "SECOND_MICROSECOND, SELECT", "SENSITIVE", "SEPARATOR, SET", "SHOW", "SMALLINT, SONAME", "SPATIAL", "SPECIFIC, SQL", "SQLEXCEPTION", "SQLSTATE, SQLWARNING", "SQL_BIG_RESULT", "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, SQL_SMALL_RESULT", "SSL", "STARTING, STRAIGHT_JOIN", "TABLE", "TERMINATED, THEN", "TINYBLOB", "TINYINT, TINYTEXT", "TO", "TRAILING, TRIGGER", "TRUE", "UNDO, UNION", "UNIQUE", "UNLOCK, UNSIGNED", "UPDATE", "USAGE, USE", "USING", "UTC_DATE, UTC_TIME", "UTC_TIMESTAMP", "VALUES, VARBINARY", "VARCHAR", "VARCHARACTER, VARYING", "WHEN", "WHERE, WHILE", "WITH", "WRITE, XOR", "YEAR_MONTH", "ZEROFILL");

/**
 * Array of field types that go unquoted.
 * @var array
 */
private $noQuoteFields = array("INTEGER", "INT", "SMALLINT", "TINYINT", "MEDIUMINT", "BIGINT", "DECIMAL", "NUMERIC", "FLOAT", "DOUBLE", "BIT");

/**
 * Array of query data
 * @var array
 */
private $queryData = array(
    "num rows" => NULL,
    "affected rows" => NULL
);

/**
 * Construct of the class
 * Connects to the database
 */
public function __construct() {
    // Connect to database and check for errors.
    $link = mysqli_connect($this->opts['HOST'], $this->opts['USER'], $this->opts['PASSWORD'], $this->opts['DATABASE NAME']);
    if(!$link) throw new DatabaseException("Database Error: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    $this->link = $link;
}

/**
 * Sends out a raw query
 * @param string
 * @return mysql result
 */
private function RawQuery($sql) {
    // Send out the query
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
    if(!$result) throw new DatabaseException("Query Error: ".mysqli_error($this->link));

    // Save some data
    $this->queryData['num rows'] = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $this->queryData['affected rows'] = mysqli_affected_rows($this->link);

    // Give back to the world
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Sends out a query
 * @return mysqli result
 */
public function Query() {
    $result = $this->RawQuery($this->PrepareQuery(func_get_args()));
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of rows that query got
 * @return int
 */
public function NumRows() {
    return $this->queryData['num rows'];
}

/**
 * Returns number of affected rows by query
 * @return int
 */
public function AffectedRows() {
    return $this->queryData['affected rows'];
}

/**
 * Returns only one row 
 * @return array
 */
public function getRow() {
    // Get result
    $result = $this->RawQuery($this->PrepareQuery(func_get_args()));

    // Build data & Give back to the world
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(count($row) > 0) return $row; 
    else return false;
}

/**
 * Returns all rows from a query
 * @return array
 */
public function getAll() {
    // Get result
    $result = $this->RawQuery($this->PrepareQuery(func_get_args()));

    // Build data
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    // Give back to the world
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Returns a single column from a query
 * @return array
 */
public function getCol() {
    // Get result
    $result = $this->RawQuery($this->PrepareQuery(func_get_args()));

    // Build data
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = reset($row);
    }

    // Give back to the world
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Returns a scalar value from a query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function GetOne() {
    // Get result and return one value
    $result = $this->RawQuery($this->PrepareQuery(func_get_args()));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(count($row) > 0) return reset($row);
    else return false;
}

/**
 * Returns all table names in the database
 * @return array
 */
private function getTables() {
    return $this->getCol("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{$this->opts['DATABASE NAME']}'");
}

/**
 * Returns all field names in the database
 * @return array
 */
private function getFields() {
    return $this->getCol("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '{$this->opts['DATABASE NAME']}'");
}

/**
 * Returns the field type of a field
 * @return string
 */
private function getFieldType($column) {
    return $this->getOne("SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = '{$column}'");
}


/**
 * Prepares a query, looks at placeholders and escapes what needs to be escaped.
 * @return string
 */
public function PrepareQuery() {
    // Get the arguments, sort of the query 
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $arguments = $arguments[0];
    $sql = array_shift($arguments);

    // Match the placeholders
    preg_match_all("(\?[sitfku])", $sql, $matches);
    $placeholders = $matches[0];

    // Check if the number of placeholders is equal to the arguments
    if(count($placeholders) != count($arguments)) throw new DatabaseException("Prepare Error: Placeholders don't match arguments.");

    // Loop over, sanitize the data, build the query
    for($i = 0; $i < count($placeholders); $i++) {

        // See what data to sanitize
        $sanitized = NULL;
        switch($placeholders[$i]) {
            case "?s":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeString($arguments[$i]);
                break;
            case "?i":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeInteger($arguments[$i]);
                break;
            case "?t":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeTableName($arguments[$i]);
                break;
            case "?f":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeFieldName($arguments[$i]);
                break;
            case "?k":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeKeyword($arguments[$i]);
                break;
            case "?u":
                $sanitized = $this->escapeUpdate($arguments[$i]);
                break;
        }

        // Replace the placeholder with the sanitized data
        $pos = strpos($sql,$placeholders[$i]);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $sql = substr_replace($sql, $sanitized, $pos, strlen($placeholders[$i]));
        }
    }

    // Give back to the world
    return $sql;
}

/**
 * Escapes a string
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
private function escapeString($string) {
    return "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->link, $string)."'";
}

/**
 * Escapes an integer
 * @param mixed
 * @return int
 */
private function escapeInteger($int) {
    return intval($int);
}

/**
 * Escapes a table name
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
private function escapeTableName($data) {
    $tables = $this->getTables();
    if(!in_array($data, $tables)) throw new DatabaseException("Invalid table name [{$data}]");
    else return $data;
}

/**
 * Escapes a field name
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
private function escapeFieldName($data) {
    $fields = $this->getFields();
    if(!in_array($data, $fields)) throw new DatabaseException("Invalid field name [{$data}]");
    else return $data;
}

/**
 * Escapes a keyword
 * @param string
 * @return string
 */
private function escapeKeyword($data) {
    if(!in_array($data, $this->mysqlKeywords)) throw new Exception("Invalid keyword [$data]");
    else return '`'.$data.'`';
}

/**
 * Escapes an update clause
 * @param array
 * @return string
 */
private function escapeUpdate($data) {
    // Check if we got an array
    if(!is_array($data)) throw new DatabaseException("Argument of ?u must be an array containing field => value pairs.");

    // Get all fields, prepare to build data
    $fields = $this->getFields();
    $sanitized = '';
    $comma = '';

    // Build data
    foreach($data as $field => $value) {
        // Check if we got a valid field name
        if(!in_array($fields, $fields)) throw new DatabaseException("{$field} is an invalid field name.");
        $data_type = $this->getFieldType($field);
        $integer = false;

        // Escape values
        if(in_array($data_type, $this->noQuoteFields)) $integer = true;
        if($integer) $value = $this->escapeInteger($value);
        else $value = $this->escapeStr($value);

        // Append shizzle, my nizzle.
        $sanitized .= "{$comma}{$field} = {$value}, ";
        $comma = ", ";
    }

    // Give back to the world
    return $sanitized;
}

public function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->link);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bug**

```
if(!in_array($fields, $fields)) throw new DatabaseException("{$field} is an invalid field name.");
```

This will always throw an exception, the first value should be `$field`.

**Unnecessary Variable**

This code is confusing:

```
    $integer = false;

    // Escape values
    if(in_array($data_type, $this->noQuoteFields)) $integer = true;
    if($integer) $value = $this->escapeInteger($value);
    else $value = $this->escapeStr($value);
```

You only use $integer in this one place, so just get rid of it (you can add a comment for clarity if you feel the need for it):

```
if(in_array($data_type, $this->noQuoteFields)) { // is integer?
    $value = $this->escapeInteger($value);
} else {
    $value = $this->escapeStr($value);
}
```

**Misc**

- you don't need `RawQuery` (you never ever call it without first having called `PrepareQuery`).
- `func_get_args` isn't a very pretty way to handle function arguments. You can't see how many or what values a function expects from the function signature, but you have to actually look into the code to see how to use a function. You will also get better error reporting with explicit arguments (too many/too few arguments, instead of ignoring additional arguments or failing somewhere inside the function). If you don't know the amount of arguments, pass an array.